# Contents Table in beamer squeezing distances

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I would like to squeeze the table of Contents in beamer from the top. Also, I would like to increase the horizontal distance for subtitles as the following picture

[image: here]

This is my code. Please suggest simple codes because I'm an absolute beginner in beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Contents:}
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5cm]{\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

%--------------------------------------------------------
%------------------/ Section 1 /-------------------------
\section{Abstract}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{1. Abstract:}}
    The primary work of my research is 
\end{frame}

%______________________________________________________
\subsection{ssssss}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{1.2. ssssssss}}
    ssssssssssssssssssssssss
\end{frame}

%______________________________________________________
\subsection{fffffff}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{1.3. ffffff}}
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
\end{frame}

%--------------------------------------------------------
%------------------/ Section 2 /-------------------------
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{2. Introduction:}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To increase the indent for subsection entries, you can use

```
\addtobeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\parshape 1 2em \dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}{}
```

(change both occurrences of `2em` to the desired length). To get the ToC at the top, use the t option for the `frame`:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Contents:}
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5cm]{\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\addtobeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\parshape 1 2em \dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Contents:}
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5cm]{\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

%--------------------------------------------------------
%------------------/ Section 1 /-------------------------
\section{Abstract}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{1. Abstract:}}
    The primary work of my research is 
\end{frame}

%______________________________________________________
\subsection{ssssss}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{1.2. ssssssss}}
    ssssssssssssssssssssssss
\end{frame}

%______________________________________________________
\subsection{fffffff}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{1.3. ffffff}}
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
\end{frame}

%--------------------------------------------------------
%------------------/ Section 2 /-------------------------
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{2. Introduction:}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]